# Lucene document structure to correctly group a collection of keys

Tags: java, lucene, compass-lucene

I have a Java model like this (some fields omitted):

```
@Searchable(root=true)
class Person {
  @SearchableProperty
  String sex;

  @SearchableProperty
  String name;
}

class Parent extends Person {
  @SearchableComponent
  List<Person> children;
}
```

This model creates a lucene document with the following data for person Anakin:

```
$/person/sex:male
$/person/name:anakin
$/person/children/sex:male
$/person/children/name:luke
$/person/children/sex:female
$/person/children/name:leia
```

Assuming this is only one of many documents, I can search like this:

1. Find persons with a name starting with an and has a male child

   ```
   $/person/name:an* AND $/person/children/sex:male
   ```
2. Find persons with a male child and a female child

   ```
   $/person/children/sex:male AND $/person/children/sex:female
   ```

I run into trouble when trying to find a child with a specific name and sex, like this

```
$/person/children/sex:male AND $/person/children/name:leia
```

This will return a result, and I can see why. I would like this to return no results. My question is how can I discriminate or associate these nested properties such that my queries return valid data?

I have considered:

1. Storing the children as separate documents, though by doing this I lose the ability to search in the way I have written above.
2. Using an `id` field somehow in the query to group these fields. I haven't been able to come up with a way which is 'right'. Variants I have considered:

   ```
   $/person/children/1/name:luke
   $/person/children/name:luke1 or $/person/children/name:1luke
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Compass, but on the Lucene level you can use BlockJoinQuery to nest the child documents into your parent document and query them.

Mike McCandless has an excellent blog post on using BlockJoinQuery in Lucene 3.4 [1]. That should give you the basic concepts. However in Lucene 4 the API has changed and is now under the `org.apache.search.lucene.join` package. There is a code example in the Javadoc [2].

[1] http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2012/01/searching-relational-content-with.html
[2] http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_10_1/join/org/apache/lucene/search/join/package-summary.html

Comment: This is definitely the right answer, but as always in software there is a caveat. The Compass framework is all but mothballed, and stuck on version 2.9 of Lucene so unfortunately I can't leverage these improvements. Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: Considering Compass development is abandoned (the author went on to develop ElasticSearch) would you not consider switching stack? If you really want the annotation abstractions there is Hibernate Search which works with Lucene http://hibernate.org/search/

Comment: Definitely something we are looking to do. I was hoping there might be something we could do in the meantime to satisfy this requirement, but that is looking like a dead end. Thanks for your help!